# Cannot invoke "io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification.get(java.net.URI)

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm learning to create a REST Assured and Cucumber framework from scratch following a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcqKnZ1NiwI&list=PL6tu16kXT9PpgqfMbMdzUzDenYgb0gbk0&index=6) on Youtube.

Below is the step definition and the method it calls in the RestAssuredExtension class.

```
@Given("^I perform GET operation for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_Perform_GET_Operation_For(String url) throws Throwable {
        RestAssuredExtension.GetOps(url);
    }
```

```
package utilities;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Map;


public class RestAssuredExtension {

public static RequestSpecification Request;

    public RestAssuredExtension() {
        //Arrange
        RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        builder.setBaseUri("http://localhost:3000/");
        builder.setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        var requestSpec = builder.build();
        Request = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpec);
    }

    public static ResponseOptions<Response> GetOps(String url)  {
        //Act
        try {
            return Request.get(new URI(url));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the video tutorial, the test passes successfully. But when I run the test myself, it results in the following error:

Step failed
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification.get(java.net.URI)" because "utilities.RestAssuredExtension.Request" is null
at utilities.RestAssuredExtension.GetOps(RestAssuredExtension.java:42)
at steps.GETPostSteps.i_Perform_GET_Operation_For(GETPostSteps.java:21)

Any takers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example you have given, I think you have not initialized the `RestAssuredExtension.Request` field.

In the video (I quickly skimmed it), they provide a hook to create a new instance of the `RestAssuredExtension` before any tests are executed.  This will ensure that the public static class variable `Request` will have been initialized to a non-null value.

My recommendation, if you want to reduce dependency for setup on the test framework and make use of static methods:

```
public final class RequestExtension {
    
    private static RequestSpecification request;

    // Ensure that no one is able to create an instance and thereby bypass proper initalization
    private RequestExtension() {

    }

    // Ensures the initialization responsibility is within the class itself and not a hidden dependency for other users.
    private static void getInstance() {
        if (request == null) {
            RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
            builder.setBaseUri("http://localhost:3000/");
            builder.setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
            var requestSpec = builder.build();
            request = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpec);
        }
        return request;
    }        

    public static ResponseOptions<Response> GetOps(String url)  {
        // Initialize
        getInstance();
        // Act
        try {
            return request.get(new URI(url));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, mixing static methods with dependencies on the instance will keep tripping people up.  Would go either with the above or remove `static` from the class altogether:

```
public class RequestExtension {

    private RequestSpecification request; 

    public RestAssuredExtension() {
        //Arrange
        RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        builder.setBaseUri("http://localhost:3000/");
        builder.setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        var requestSpec = builder.build();
        request = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpec);
    }

    public ResponseOptions<Response> GetOps(String url)  {
        //Act
        try {
            return request.get(new URI(url));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

One thing to help with debugging is to follow Java naming conventions.  The capitalisation of your class field `RequestSpecification` makes it read as a class not a field name.  (`Request` vs `request`)  It was the same in the video so its a source issue. :)

Comment: Thank you @fakataha. I've gone ahead with your second recommendation removing static from the RestAssuredExtension class altogether. However in the step definition 

public ResponseOptions<Response> response;

@Given("^I perform GET operation for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_Perform_GET_Operation_For(String url) throws Throwable {
    response = RestAssuredExtension.getOps(url);
}

I'm getting an alert that RestAssuredExtension.getOps should be static.

Comment: If I was to incorporate your first recommendation, do i remove the TestInitialise class? package steps;

import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import utilities.RestAssuredExtension;

public class TestInitialize {

        @Before
        public void TestSetup(){
            RestAssuredExtension restAssuredExtension = new RestAssuredExtension();
        }
}

Comment: For the first recommendation, you wouldn't need to tie it in to the framework by using @Before.  The class would be responsible for ensuring that the RequestSpecification was initialized by calling getInstance().  Downside is that this would be needed for all static methods that expect to use that static field.

Comment: i've reverted to your first recommendation and removed the hook class that was part of the tutorial. working fine now. Thank you very much for your time resolving this issue for me.